# Follower lost custom equipment after wedding

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've had Illia as my follower since level 25-ish and she carries most of my rare equipment that I don't have room for. However, I recently married some random in the game and then continued about my missions. Several quests later, to my horror she is wearing her original robes and all my sweet equipment is gone! Can I get this stuff back, or is it lost forever?

Comment: When you say "several quests later", did it disappear several quest later? or did you just only notice it was gone at that point? (If the former, then the wedding probably had nothing to do with it)

Comment: I only noticed several quests later.. But i read that if she is your follower she will change back to her robes during the ceremony.. But what happens to all the stuff she had

Comment: Im a bit of a skyrim horder when it comes to unique wepons and armor, so i was pretty butt hurt when i lost the dragon priest mask and eye of melka staff

Comment: Revert to a past save. Check any of the storage that she would have access to. (houses she has lived in or frequented maybe) ...but uhh m'afraid that bethesda didn't think far enough ahead to follower inventory's and costume changes. are you playing on a pc where you might save them from some cache or something? or perhaps just "god in" some replacements for them? -Personally i just broke the game with crafted and enchanted stuff to make my inventory huge... i never trusted any of the sprites with any of my stuff. I never used bookshelves for the same reason. lost a few good books, never again